# Dynamic XPath to filter XML documents using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-3.0

I have been searching StackOverflow for a while yet unsuccessful. My aim is to filter Employee XML documents. The Input XML has around 9000 Employees, and I have multiple target systems who wants a subset of these Employee Records based on different selection criteria for each target system.
Sample Input:

```
<Employees>
  <Employee>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Name1</name>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>Name2</name>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <id>3</id>
    <name>Name3</name>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <id>4</id>
    <name>Name4</name>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

The output should be of the same structure but reduced  nodes based on the selection criteria(XPATH).
How can I pass the dynamic XPath to an XSLT stylesheet and get the filtered employees as output? **Please note the complete Xpath Expression along with the filtering conditions** are passed as one string.

Desired output:

```
<Employees>
      <Employee>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Name2</name>
      </Employee>
      <Employee>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>Name3</name>
      </Employee>
 </Employees>
```

Comment: Maintaing the root node is optional. The root node can be ignored and the output can be just with multiple Employee Nodes matching the selection criteria as well.

Comment: In XSLT 3 using a static parameter and a shadow attribute this is straightforward, with the exception that you need to use an XSLT 3 processor and its API or interface to use that feature.

Comment: You might consider just using XPath in your program to do the filtering, in C# for example using XmlDocument.SelectNodes( "//your/dynamic/xapth[@filter=1]" ).  Then format the results in XSL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With XSLT 3.0, [`xsl:evaluate`](http://w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-evaluate) for dynamic XPath evaluation. You could accept the XPath as an `xsl:param` (shown with an example default XPath value) and then evaluate it.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
    <xsl:param name="path" select="'/Employees/Employee[number(id)[. gt 1 and . lt 4]]'" />
        
    <xsl:template match="Employees">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:evaluate xpath="$path" context-item="."/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This code only returns the values inside the nodes, and not as XML output.

Comment: well, you haven't provided an example of the desired output, so it's difficult to guess what you want. You can make it well-formed XML output by wrapping the apply-templates in some element, you can copy the document element, etc.

Comment: Updated the desired output. Does the evaluate function return just the values, or it returns along with the node information?

Comment: `xsl:evaluate` will return the nodes, which you can simply return in the template, instead of applying templates if you aren't going to transform or filter anything. I have updated the solution.